# MySQL: update multiple rows, ignore empty values?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update multiple row and ignore empty values?

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (id, v1, v2)
VALUES
    (1,  2,  3),
    (4,   ,   ),
    (7,  8,  9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
v1=VALUES(v1), v2=VALUES(v2);
```

How do I not overwrite data like (v1, v2) at id=4?
i.e. is it possible, if data is blank (or specially formatted in other way), not overwrite it in DB given id is duplicate and update is to occur?

Comment: p.s., curious how did I get -2 pt during the first 45 seconds? Sounds like less then enough time even to read the question.

Comment: Not my downvote here, but it's probably because you didn't post the actual query that you tried and included any errors you may have had, if any. I can't speak for the downvoters, but that could be it, or part of it. There's also no php here, as per the tag you used for it.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @bbe, also, FYI, there are review queues for new questions, that are constantly monitored by community (accessible when you reach sufficient reputation).

Answer (score 0):

The only check i would see here is to do insert ... on duplicate only after 1 check if all the variables are there.

```
if(isset($value_for_col1) && isset($value_for_col2) && ...){ do insert }
```

Or you can set your columns in structure as "not null" and any insert will not work as you can't add an insert without parsing an value to all the required field